# How to apply map function to a tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a 4D tensor and if I run it, all values expect for 1/100 part are rather close to what I need, so I want to apply a map function which will set all bad numbers to some fixed value. And the question is: how can I apply a map function in terms of tensors, i.e. BEFORE the Session()'s run function (as I need to calculate a loss function and backpropagate the result, these operations are made before sess.run).

Answer (score 2):

You can't work with python's `map` function because tensorflow works with symbolic tensors which will only be filled the moment you run `session.run()`. But there is a map function for tensors provided by tensorflow, called `tf.map_fn` see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn